# Retrofit & Gson assign field from header and cookie?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

Currently, I'm returning a `Response` from retrofit and manually parse my object. Is there a cleaner way to do this using annotation or a custom deserializer?

```
@GET("/login")
fun login(username: String): Single<Auth>
```

Model

```
class Auth {
   @SerializedName("id")
   val userId: String

   @Header("secret")
   val secret: String

   @Cookie("token")
   val token: String
}
```